# Revert emails fetched via django-mailbox, back to Gmail inbox

Tags: django, gmail, imap

I am a Django newbie. I have setup a mailbox in Django admin using the django-mailbox package. The URI configuration was a Gmail IMAP email server. While retrieving mails into my Django mailbox, they got deleted from the  inbox and got created as db records. Is there a way to revert the emails back to the Gmail inbox, either using a Django API, gsuite's email recovery, or exporting data from db into Gmail inbox?

Thanks in advance for your help.
P.S. the mails are not present in the trash folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try iterating over each django_mailbox.Message
instance, use the get_email_object method to help generate a MIME message, then use IMAP APPEND to put the message back in your online mailbox.